# Upload a base 64 image on post call to firebase storage by cloud function in typescript

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

Hi I want to upload a image to the firebase storage by cloud function below is my code where its showing in the bucket but with broken image.Thanks in advance.

```
var base64EncodedImageString = driverDetails.profilePhoto,
                            mimeType = 'image/jpeg',
                            fileName = 'Thumbnail64.jpg';
                        const imageBuffer = new Buffer(base64EncodedImageString, 'base64');
                        var bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
                        var file = bucket.file('profile-imagesss/' + fileName);
                        file.save(imageBuffer, {
                            metadata: { contentType: mimeType },
                        })
```

where driverDetails.profilePhoto is the base64 image sending on body like data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAA

Comment: Why are you uploading a base64 encoded string to Cloud Storage? You need to decode it and upload the raw bytes.

Comment: i didn't get your answer.Do you have any sample example.Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot i got you logic and thats did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The first challenge with your code is
`const imageBuffer = new Buffer(base64EncodedImageString, 'base64');`

Use this instead

`const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(base64EncodedImageString, 'base64');`

Secondly, you are creating a buffer from the base64 data with the mime data so to speak.

Finally, you have not given a token metadata

The code below works

```
const { photo } = data

    const { nanoid } = require("nanoid")

    const filename = nanoid() + '.jpg'

    const getBase64MimeType = encoded => {
        let result = null
        if (typeof encoded !== 'string') {
            return result
        }
        const mime = encoded.match(/data:([a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9-.+]+).*,.*/)
        if (mime && mime.length) {
            result = mime[1]
        }
        return result
    }

    const getBase64Data = encoded => {
        const base64EncodedString = encoded.replace(/^data:\w+\/\w+;base64,/,'')
        return base64EncodedString
    }

    const contentType = getBase64MimeType(photo)

    const photoData = getBase64Data(photo)

    const fileBuffer = Buffer.from(photoData,"base64")

    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket()

    const token = nanoid()

    const options = {
        metadata: {
            contentType,
            metadata: {
                firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: token,
            }
        },
    }

    const filePath = 'membership/' + filename

    const file = bucket.file(filePath)

    await file.save(fileBuffer,options)
```